# Sshd_config still allowing password authentication

Tags: ssh, password, sshd

I have adapted my sshd_config file where I changed the value of:

- PasswordAuthentication no
- ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
- usePAM no ( now set to yes)

Furthermore I have restarted the sshd service by executing: `sudo service ssh restart`. I have also done a reboot.

I am still allowed to login with a user password. Any idea what I have been missing?

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no
```

#### EDIT:

- `PermitRootLogin` is now set to `no`.
- `usePAM` is now set to `yes`.

Still not working though.

Comment: Shouldn't this `PermitRootLogin yes` be `PermitRootLogin no`?

Comment: Changed it to 'no' but still allowing to login with password

Comment: Did a reboot after changing that?

Comment: I have done now, still allowing it. I am using openssh-server and installed it today

Comment: @MattiasDeCharleroy You broke things.  You removed a line you should've kept, and you should be using PAM, per my answer.

Comment: How do you test that it is still allowed?

Comment: First I do a restart of the ssh service on the device. Then I open a new terminal from my laptop and ssh to the device (in this case a raspberry pi).  I get a password prompt and fill in the password, which succeeds.

Answer (score 8):

You need to do three things here:

(1) Set `PermitRootLogin` to be `without-password` or `restrict-password` or `no`.  For security.  I normally set it to `no`.

(2) You're missing something else that's pretty important.  You should be using PAM for authentication for things - `UsePAM yes` is what the default usually is; this allows you to use UNIX user login data.

(3) Also important, NORMALLY you set `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to `no`.  This protects from bypassing the `without-password` restriction for `root` logon.  (The exception is if you're using `libpam-duo` and the Duo Security 2FA system, in which case you need `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` set to `yes`, but this isn't a typical setup.)

Once you've done that, `sudo service ssh restart` to restart the SSH service with the new configuration.  Attempt SSH from another window before you logout of your SSH session to make sure things are working as expected.

Comment: PermitRootLogin is now set to no.
UsePAM is now set to yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication is still set to no.
I have restarted the service but still to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I followed Thomas' steps but still didn't work. Turns out I just needed to set `UsePAM` to `no` and it now disallows login without a public key.

Answer (score 0):

This disallows password logins for me:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
UsePAM yes
```

Then

```
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
```