# Chages to sshd_config not disable password only login

Tags: ssh, password, security, remote-access

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS installed as a virtual machine (Windows Hyper-V). I am making the following changes to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

After the changes are made `sudo sshd -t` throws no errors.

I have tried many options (list below) to restart/reload sshd service:

```
sudo service sshd restart
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
sudo service sshd reload
sudo systemctl reload sshd.service
sudo kill -SIGHUP $(pgrep -f "sshd -D")
```

but regardless of the command (or even if I execute all of them) I am still able to log into virtual machine providing password only. Even after reebot I can log into virtual machine.

For clarification the virtual machine is running on ip 172.30.42.222 while WSL from which I am login in runs on 172.30.32.1

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** This [AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/922328/32664) may help resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem was solved. I have commented one line in

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf
```

and of course the line was

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

First uncommented line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is `Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` which indicates that the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf` is included into `sshd_config`. However the line `PasswordAuthentication no` is sshd_config comes after the `Include...` line which suggest that the latter line should be valid.

Can anyone comment on that issue?

Comment: From `man sshd_config`: *"For each keyword, the first obtained value will be used."*

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1440509/1713168

> Inside the directory /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/ there is only one .conf
> file (50-cloud-init.conf), but inside it contains the line:
> PasswordAuthentication yes
>
> I changed the line to #PasswordAuthentication no
>
> and i restarted the ssh. Now is working. I can only access with the
> ssh key.